# Android: Network connectivity check always fail

Tags: java, android

in my app there is a modul with a weather activity. When the user click and activate the weather function there is a check for network connectivity. The Problem is, direct on start, there comes my toast message "No network connectivity" with the Android Dialog to enable.

When the user click "enable" there is nothing to activate in the options (Everything is on).
When the user click "cancel" the Dialog disappears and the app is working.

Here is my code from the activity:

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);
    // Connect the client.
    mLocationClient.connect();

    // Registers BroadcastReceiver to track network connection changes.
    mNetworkReceiver = new NetworkReceiver() {
        private MyAlertDialog enableNetworkDialog = null;

        @Override
        public void onNoConnectivity() {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    getString(R.string.network_disabled), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // If the dialog already prompted, do nothing
            if (enableNetworkDialog != null
                    && enableNetworkDialog.isShowing())
                return;

            // Prompt a dialog for user to open the network settings screen
            enableNetworkDialog = new MyAlertDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    null, getString(R.string.network_disabled), false);
            enableNetworkDialog.setPositiveButton("Enable",
                    new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            toggleNetworkSourceSetting();
                        }
                    });
            enableNetworkDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            enableNetworkDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnect() {
            if (enableNetworkDialog != null
                    && enableNetworkDialog.isShowing())
                enableNetworkDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNetworkChange() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onReconnect() {
        }
    };
}
```

UPDATE: This is my manifest:

```
 <!-- Grant the network access permission -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

This are cutouts from my logcat:

```
[ 07-19 10:43:17.876 18037:18037 D/         ]
                                                              Current Network Info : NetworkInfo: type: mobile_supl[HSPA+, type_ext: mobile_supl], state: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED, reason: dataDisabled, extra: internet.telekom, roaming: false, failover: false, isAvailable: true, isConnectedToProvisioningNetwork: false, isIpv4Connected: false, isIpv6Connected: false

[ 07-19 10:43:17.876 18037:18037 D/         ]
                                                              No network is available

07-19 10:43:19.778 18037-18037/bakteriusdeveloper.master D/Network Connection: mobile is available
```

Update super method:

```
    /**
 * The subclass of the BroadcastReeiver is used to detect the change of
 * connectivity.
 * 
 */
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public NetworkReceiver() {
        super();
    }

    public void onNoConnectivity() {
    };

    public void onNetworkChange() {
    };

    public void onConnect() {
    };

    public void onReconnect() {
    };

    public void toggleNetworkSourceSetting() {
        startActivity(new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager conn = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activNetworkInfo = conn.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        String failMessage = intent
                .getStringExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_REASON);
        Logger.printMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(), failMessage,
                Logger.DEBUG);
        Boolean isNoConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        Boolean isFailOver = intent.getBooleanExtra(
                ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_IS_FAILOVER, false);
        Logger.printMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(), "is Failover: "
                + isFailOver, Logger.DEBUG);
        Boolean isNetworkChanged = false;

        NetworkInfo otherNetworkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_OTHER_NETWORK_INFO);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                .getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

        Logger.printMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "Current Network Info : " + networkInfo, Logger.DEBUG);
        Logger.printMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                "Other Network Info : " + otherNetworkInfo, Logger.DEBUG);

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            if (isFailOver) {
                Logger.printMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "Network is re-connected and available now",
                        Logger.DEBUG);
                onReconnect();
                return;
            } else {
                Logger.printMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "Network is available", Logger.DEBUG);
                onConnect();
                return;
            }

        } else if (networkInfo != null
                && !networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            // do application-specific task(s) based on the current network
            // state, such
            // as enabling queuing of HTTP requests when currentNetworkInfo
            // is connected etc.
            if (otherNetworkInfo != null
                    && otherNetworkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
                isNetworkChanged = true;
            } else {
                Logger.printMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "No network is available", Logger.DEBUG);
                onNoConnectivity();
                return;
            }
        }

        // No network is active OR no network is available
        if (activNetworkInfo == null || isNoConnectivity) {
            if (isNetworkChanged) {
                Logger.printMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "Change network connectivity", Logger.DEBUG);
                onNetworkChange();
                return;
            } else {
                Logger.printMessage(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "No network is available", Logger.DEBUG);
                onNoConnectivity();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Whats wrong with my request? Any ideas?

Comment: what is  your error?

Comment: does your app-manifest has internet-permission?

Comment: Hi, my error is, that the message always pop up. Even if the Network connection on!

Answer (score 0):

You can register the NetworkReceiver in onResume instead of onStart and check if it works

Comment: Is NetworkReceiver a broadcast receiver, if yes where is the on receive method?

Comment: Okay... In this case, i give up. For me now, I deleted the Button for enable the network connection. Now i have only a Toast Message, if the network is enabled or not. Cant find the reason. It seems, first the data are loading succesfull and after loading the message "no network connection" pops up. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added network permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Register a broadcastreceiver in your manifest also:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".NetworkReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Then the NetworkReceiver class:

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static volatile boolean connected;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Network", "Network changed");
        if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
            update();
        }
    }

    public static void update() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) ApplicationLoader
                .applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        connected = networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected();
    }

    public static boolean isConnected() {
        return connected;
    }
}
```

Then if you want to check the network status call:

```
NetworkReceiver.update(); // Updates network status
if (NetworkReceiver.isConnected()) {
    // do whatever you want.
}
```